Service account cannot get resource \"sparkapplications/status\" in API group \"sparkoperator.k8s.io\"
I updated my Airflow from version 2.30 to 2.9.3. Now I'm trying to run a spark job and I'm getting this error (SparkPodOperator):
[2024-08-30, 13:57:04 UTC] {spark_kubernetes.py:282} INFO - Creating sparkApplication.
[2024-08-30, 13:57:04 UTC] {base.py:84} INFO - Using connection ID 'kubernetes_default' for task execution.
[2024-08-30, 13:57:04 UTC] {custom_object_launcher.py:312} ERROR - Exception when attempting to create spark job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/custom_object_launcher.py", line 300, in start_spark_job
    while self.spark_job_not_running(self.spark_obj_spec):
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/custom_object_launcher.py", line 319, in spark_job_not_running
    spark_job_info = self.custom_obj_api.get_namespaced_custom_object_status(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/custom_objects_api.py", line 1927, in get_namespaced_custom_object_status
    return self.get_namespaced_custom_object_status_with_http_info(group, version, namespace, plural, name, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/custom_objects_api.py", line 2034, in get_namespaced_custom_object_status_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 348, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 180, in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 373, in request
    return self.rest_client.GET(url,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 244, in GET
    return self.request("GET", url,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 238, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'b822ab33-691b-49bf-bdfd-5e355c465c0e', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': '21960dd0-b9d3-43db-abbc-680540cb1fb8', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '2b2dc621-5a20-4eef-a225-8b780bc64442', 'Date': 'Fri, 30 Aug 2024 13:57:04 GMT', 'Content-Length': '487'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io \"spark-job-test-12345\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:airflow-v2:airflow-worker\" cannot get resource \"sparkapplications/status\" in API group \"sparkoperator.k8s.io\" in the namespace \"airflow-v2\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"spark-job-test-12345","group":"sparkoperator.k8s.io","kind":"sparkapplications"},"code":403}


I already set my cluster role and cluster role binding to the airflow-worker service account:
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs                     Resource Names     Verbs
sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io          []                                    []                 [*]

Anyone has any idea of what could be happening? Or how can I debug it?
This is my cluster role:
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: spark-cluster-cr
  labels:
    rbac.authorization.kubeflow.org/aggregate-to-kubeflow-edit: "true"
rules:
 - apiGroups:
 - sparkoperator.k8s.io
  resources:
 - sparkapplications
  verbs:
 - "*"


This is my role binding:
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: airflow-v2-spark-crb
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: spark-cluster-cr
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: airflow-worker
  namespace: airflow-v2


So, I found out that you just need to explicitly include the status on the resources of the cluster role:
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: spark-cluster-cr
  labels:
    rbac.authorization.kubeflow.org/aggregate-to-kubeflow-edit: "true"
rules:
 - apiGroups:
 - sparkoperator.k8s.io
  resources:
 - sparkapplications
 - sparkapplications/status
  verbs:
 - "*"


I know little about the spark operator, of how you deployed it (helm chart?), but this error looks like plain RBAC. You may want to take this issue up with the maintainers of the spark operator.
Either way, grant your operator service account ability to work with the  CRDs
Make or extend a role or clusterrole and binding:

system:serviceaccount:airflow-v2:airflow-worker
"group":"sparkoperator.k8s.io"
"kind":"sparkapplications"
"verbs": "get, list watch"  (probably)


this is the cluster role associated with the service account:
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
name: spark-cluster-cr
labels:
rbac.authorization.kubeflow.org/aggregate-to-kubeflow-edit: "true"
rules:

apiGroups:

sparkoperator.k8s.io
resources:
sparkapplications
verbs:
"*"



